# Pushing UITabBarController causes UITabBar to be transparent during animation in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, ios7, uitabbar

I have a UIViewController, and based on user input I push a UITabBarController on to the navigation stack using a push segue. While the push is animating, the UITabBar becomes transparent. When the animation has completed, the UITabBar is no longer transparent (the desired effect). This occurs on iOS 7 only, and happens during the pop animation as well.

Any ideas how I can ensure the UITabBar is fully opaque during the animation?

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setRootViewController:tabBar];
```

instead of

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:YES];
```

To switch between navigationController and tabBarController.

Comment: This works but I could achieve the same effect by removing the animation when pushing the view controller. The UITabBar seems to be transparent only while the push animation is running. After that it's opaque again.